# Core Plot : How to set two data labels for each candle stick in candle stick graph?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, core-plot

I want to set two data labels for each candle stick in candle stick graph, one data label above candle stick and the other data label below the candle stick.
In the example provided by Core Plot Framework, one data label is present for each candle stick by default, and I am not able to set the second data label. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might want to ask for help specifically on the Core Plot group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreplot-discuss

Did you read this? https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/WhereToAskForHelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make plot space annotations for the second labels or create a second plot. Have the second plot only display data labels but no plot data (set all line styles and fills to `nil`).